# 'Method not found' error with Windows Service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-services, entity-framework-5

I have a windows service written in C# using VS2012 and 4.5 Framework.  My service consists of 2 other projects that are basically objects to my databases, but they use .edmx files and EF5.

**EDMX Projects:**
`MyCompany.Data.MasterDB`
`MyCompany.Data.StatsTracker`

The service makes 2 calls to methods within itself; 1 generates a List of files to process and if there is more than 0, it returns true, otherwise false.... and the other method actually process these files.

```
//Only proceed if there are files to process.
if (GenerateFileList())
    ProcessLogs();
```

The 2nd method (called `ProcessLogs`) is where the I try to use the Context from the other projects and is where I am getting the following error:

`Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet1<MyCompany.Data.MasterDB.StatisticLogType>MyCompany.Data.MasterDB.MasterDBContext.get_StatisticLogTypes()'.`

Here's a few lines of the `ProcessLogs` method (this is wrapped in a Try/Catch):

```
StatisticLogType duplicatesLogType;
StatisticLogType successLogType;
MasterDBContext scContext = new MasterDBContext();
StatsTrackerContext utContext = new StatsTrackerContext();

//I believe this is where the error is coming from:
successLogType = scContext.StatisticLogTypes
                                .Where(s => s.StatisticLogTypeID == (int)StatisticLogTypes.LogTypes.Success).FirstOrDefault<StatisticLogType>();

duplicatesLogType = scContext.StatisticLogTypes
                                    .Where(s => s.StatisticLogTypeID == (int)StatisticLogTypes.LogTypes.Duplicates).FirstOrDefault<StatisticLogType>();
```

`StatisticLogTypes.LogTypes` is a static enum class residing in the `MasterDB` object:

```
public static class StatisticLogTypes
{
    public enum LogTypes
    {
        CorruptFile = 1,
        Success = 2,
        Duplicates = 3,
        LocationNotFound = 4,
        SystemNotFound = 5,
        BadFileNameFormat = 6,
        Uploaded = 7,
        FileNotFound = 8,
        InvalidFileExtension = 9
    }
}
```

Sorry it's a bit scattered, but I'm trying not to leave anything out.....so the project compiles and builds successfully and I can even install it using InstallShield Lite just fine.  When I run it and attach the VS debugger to it, I see that it goes through the `GenerateFileList()` method just fine, but as soon as I try to walk through `ProcessLogs()`, I get that error.  It doesn't actually let me step through the `ProcessLogs()` method line by line, which I found weird.

At any rate, I've done a ton of research trying to figure out the issue but can't seem to find anything.  I've made sure all my projects are on the same .NET Framework version but that hasn't helped.

Any help or direction would be great.  This has me stumped and I've been trying to find a resolution for days now.

BTW, I meant to add that I added a TestUnit to the project and put all the logic from the service into it and was able to run it without any issues.

Comment: Sounds like there is some kind of problem with the DLL containing `MasterDBContext` (ie something like that there's an old version in the directory where you run the project)

Comment: I have cleared all the DLL's in both the bin and obj directories (including Debug and Release folders), cleaned the solution and rebuilt it.  When I uninstall the service, I make sure the directory where it's ran from is completely removed and there's nothing left behind.

Comment: Try adding a static dummy method to the `MasterDbContext` class (or anything in its assembly/dll) and call it before you get to the code you're describing. Does that also blow up with MissingMethodException? If so, it still seems like a versioning problem, if not, it has at least been completely excluded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Joachim was onto something.  The dll was an older reference but not by accident but more fault to InstallShield LE that is built into VS2012.  My project was referencing the correct dll and when I was building the setup project, I made sure to select the output for my project but when it was being built, it was referencing an older version of that DLL.  No matter how many times I deleted the Setup project and recreated it, it always kept that older reference.  I ended up completely removing the project that created the DLL and recreating it with a different name, then InstallShield picked up the correct dll and it worked.

Hope this helps someone else!